# How to make an image align vertically in responsive design?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');

.container1{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.square:hover {
    -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
    -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    transform: translate(10px, -10px);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
     }


.square{
  width: 460px;
    height: 430px;
    background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease; 
}

@media (max-width: 375px) {
.container1{
   flex-flow: row nowrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
}

.mask{
  clip: rect(0px, 460px, 220px, 0px) !important;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
}


.h11{
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 240px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}
p9 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
    background-color: #3EDD84;
    color: white;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 70px;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'merriweather';
}
```

```html
<section>
                  <div class="section-title">
          <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
          </div>
    <div class="column1">
      <div class="row1">
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="square">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1504610926078-a1611febcad3?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=e1c8fe0c9197d66232511525bfd1cc82&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1100&q=80" class="mask">
     <div class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</div>
        <p9>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p9>
        
     <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <!-- new start of blog -->
    <div class="column1">
      <div class="row1">
    <div class="container1">
      <div class="square">
        <img src="https://www.isfasports.gr/image/cache/data/products/pr_3-1100x1100.jpg" class="mask">
     <div class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</div>
        <p9>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p9>
        
     <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      
</section>
```

Over here, the blogs cards are placed vertically, but on my end I am getting the output as:

[image]

On a smaller device, I would like the cards to be placed vertically with the `max-width` to be `80%`, I tried using the media query for this, but it still does not work on my end. Over here, for some reason, its showing the cards vertically but on my end, it shows them side-by-side. Any suggestions?

Comment: inside the media query, isn't `flex-flow: column nowrap` that you want? to make it one above the other (vertical)?

Comment: Yes but its not working for me, I am still getting that output I sent

Comment: Please, could you provide a snippet/fiddle that reproduce the problem? When I run the snippet here, the cards are vertically displayed

Comment: Yes, but I have the whole code of the blog embedded in my website, so its not possible for me to share the whole code and whats causing the problem. I am wondering if there is any other way to make them aligned/force them to be aligned using `!important`

Comment: Trying to give us the code that reproduce your issue will probably show you where it goes nuts. Did you use your browser inspector tools to see what style are applied ?